# DBAccount as a @property in iOS Dropbox Datastore API

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I'm looking at the sample tasks app that uses the Dropbox datastore API: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/downloads/sdks/datastore/ios/dropbox-ios-sync-sdk-3.0.0.zip

Inside `TasksController.m` is an `account` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) DBAccount *account;
```

In other areas of the class, this account as referenced as `self.account`, and I noticed there's this private method:

```
- (DBAccount *)account {
    return self.accountManager.linkedAccount;
}
```

...but I'm unsure of how that relates to the `readonly` property.

Where is `account` initialized for use? If it's inside the above method, I don't see anywhere that this method is called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`account` is a property, so the `-account` method is called any time you access it.

(If it were not marked `readonly`, there would be a corresponding method `-setAccount` that would be invoked any time you assigned a value to the property.)

The "properties" section here covers this a bit: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/.